# HTML5 required readonly input not posting

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out the cause of a missing post value. The input below doesn't seem to be included in the post data that is sent to an external site. This failure seems to occur over 3/4 of the time, based on the external site data stored. It's a Post-Get-Post pattern and I do get post data returned.

I've written a very simple HTML5 form using Bootstrap 3. It does a simple post. There is Javascript validation that occurs, but there's no ajax post involved. It's not a cross-site scripting issue.

I'm thinking it has to do with the support of the required attribute or the combination of the required attribute with a readonly attribute. I'm using the required attribute to trigger off some validation message help blocks.

After writing this question, I'm starting to realize that having both required and readonly attributes doesn't make sense. Has anyone tested this on various browsers?

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ssl_customer_code"><?php echo (!empty($type) && $type == 'invoice') ? '* Client Account #' : 'Account Number'; ?></label>  
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input id="ssl_customer_code" name="ssl_customer_code" type="text" value="<?php echo (!empty($ssl_customer_code)) ? htmlspecialchars($ssl_customer_code) : ''; ?>" 
               placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required readonly>
        <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Enter account number or reference number here.</span>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you already know the customer code on the server side you should probably ask yourself, do I really need to transmit it to the client and back, and the security implications of that. If its a value in the session, you could just read it from the session when the form is submitted, for instance.

Comment: @developerwjk - Due to strict PCI compliance issues, I'm not able to record much on "our" server; security implications. The data is posted directly. I can't see the data posted. I only see a response from the external site posted back to us; ssl_approval_code, etc. ssl_customer_code is not included for some strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps

```
value="<?php echo (!empty($ssl_customer_code)) ? htmlspecialchars($ssl_customer_code) : ''; ?>"
```

should be

```
value="<?php echo (!empty($ssl_customer_code) ? htmlspecialchars($ssl_customer_code) : ''); ?>"
```

?